# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: it.*.PoolStateResult | Map a result in a DTO (not an Entity)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pojo, dto

Using:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

this is my DTO. It is not an Entity on DB. I want to use it only for mapping

```
public class PoolStateResult {

    private Integer totalCodes;
    private Integer assignedCodes;
    private Integer availableCodes;

    private Date startDateValidate;
    private Date endDateValidate;

constructors
getters and setters
```

this is the content of DAO

```
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("  SELECT p.start_validity_date as startDateValidate, "
            + " p.end_validity_date as endDateValidate, "
            + " (SELECT count(*) from POOL_CODES p WHERE p.id_pool = :poolCode) as totalCodes, "
            + " (SELECT count(*) "
            + " from VOUCHER v "
            + " WHERE v.id_reference_pool = :poolCode "
            + " AND v.status = 'ASSEGNATO') as assignedCodes, "
            + " (SELECT count(*) "
            + " from VOUCHER v, POOL_CODES p "
            + " WHERE v.id_reference_pool = p.id_pool "
            + " AND v.id_reference_pool = :poolCode "
            + " AND v.status = 'ASSEGNATO' "
            + " and p.end_validity_date < sysdate) as availableCodes "
            + " from POOL_CODES p "
            + " WHERE p.id_pool = :poolCode",PoolStateResult.class);

    q.setParameter("poolCode", "poolCode"); 
    return (PoolStateResult) q.getSingleResult();
```

I add this package in configuration class

```
entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                env.getProperty("entitymanager.packages.to.scan"),
```

this is the exception

```
javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:532)
```

Is there a way to force the mapping automatically as for all entity tables or the only way, with hibernate, for these types of queries is writing the mapping?
Is this the best and only way to map a non-entity Java object using Hibernate?

```
 @SqlResultSetMapping(
               name="getPoolStateResult",
               classes={
                  @ConstructorResult(
                       targetClass=PoolStateResult.class,
                         columns={
                            @ColumnResult(name="totalCodes", type=Integer.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="assignedCodes", type=Integer.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="availableCodes", type=Integer.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="startDateValidate", type=Date.class),
                            @ColumnResult(name="endValidityDate", type=Date.class)
                            }
                  )
               }
              )
```

Then, where would the advantages of hibernate in this case?

Thanks

Comment: The exception you mentioned in the problem description is not related to the issue with mapping, but to using ```q.getSingleResult();```. You see, this method throws an exception when there is no record in database that matches your selection criteria.

Comment: I'm sure that I have result in database. If I execute query on Db it works.
Also  writing the mapping IT works.

Comment: `p.end_validity_date as endValidityDate` - there is no membervariable in your DTO that is called endValidityDate. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running this exact query manually and looked at the result?

Comment: @Cashbee i edited It the problem is the same.

Comment: If I run the query on DB it works correctly

Comment: You could _translate_ this SQL query to JPQL/HQL which will look almost the same and use JPQL constructor expressions instead of the sql result set mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No JPA and Hibernate can't automatically map a query result to a DTO without any mapping information. You either map the result programmatically or you define a constructor call in an `@SqlResultSetMapping`, as you did in your example.

You don't need to do that if you want to map the result to an entity. Hibernate then tries to use the mapping definition of the entity to map the query result. So, your query result needs to return all entity attributes and they have to have the same name as you use in your entity mapping. I explained that in more details in a [series of blog posts about `@SqlResultMapping`](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-basics/).

Regarding the benefits of using Hibernate for such a query: 
Hibernate doesn't provide you any benefits if this is the only database interaction you perform in a transaction. But it allows you to use this query within a Hibernate session and therefore within the same transaction as all other operations Hibernate performs in that session.

Comment: Thanks. About @SqlResultSetMapping:

EclipseLink--> put it at any class in the classpath;      

Hibernate--> put it at any class annotated with @Entity;

Is this right?

Comment: I'm not sure about EclipseLink but it's right for Hibernate. It ignores the annotation if you put it into package-info.java or a non-entity classes

Answer (score 0):

Try to alter a bit your query creation:

**1)** Add the `NEW package.Class` to the select list

```
String queryString = 
         "SELECT new com.mypackage.PoolStateResult("
             +  "p.start_validity_date as startDateValidate, "
             + " p.end_validity_date as endValidityDate, "
            + " (SELECT count(*) from POOL_CODES p WHERE p.id_pool = :poolCode) as totalCodes, "
            + " (SELECT count(*) "
            + ")"
            + " from VOUCHER v " 
               ...
```

**2)** Use the createNativeQuery method to which you pass the sql mapping name as the second param:

```
em.createNativeQuery(queryString, "getPoolStateResult");
```

Comment: hi, writing the mapping IT works, even without changing the query. The question is precisely if I can have the same result without writing the mapper but only using the DTO PoolStateResult (such as an Entity)

Comment: you can try setting the: .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(PoolStateResult .class)) on the Query

Comment: setResultTransformer is deprecated or don't exists in hibernate 5